# How to deallocate subviews upon window closing

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I have started to use the Apple Instruments to detect memory leaks.
When I open a new window in my app and that window contains a tableview and then
I close the window down Instruments still says it is "living".
So the living variable for the tableview keeps increasing for each time I open and close the window.

I thought that all views on the closing window would be removed upon closing but it is not.
I have also tried this to "null" it out but that did not difference (I am using ProMotion).

```
def will_dismiss

 @table = nil

end
```

Any ideas how to deallocate subviews?

Comment: this is why people don't use rubymotion  ;-)  the obscure approach ... (void)didMoveToWindow { if ( self.window == nil ) [self removeFromSuperview]; } can sometimes help, cheers

Comment: Setting reference to `nil` isn't help. You should use `autorelease pool`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this method is being called? Have you confirmed that no one is holding a reference to the view of that `viewController`

Answer (score 1):

Using of **instance variables** and **autorelease pool** is the best advice from RubyMotion for correcting "automatic memory management". They still improving GC (and trying to be closer to standart Ruby GC) [similar to ARC by design](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_memory_management). So, if you want to be sure some var will be collected by GC, you have to place it's usage inside autorelease pool block. This approach guarantees cleaning and rescue from unexpected memory leaks.

```
autorelease_pool do
   @table
end
```

Comment: Is there an authoritative source that says not to use nil and that the `autorelease_pool` is the way to go? I've read the memory management section in the RubyMotion documentation but it didn't appear to be that clear cut about it.